# List category posts - thumbnail_size problem

Tags: support

I'm using the list category posts plugin, and can't get the thumbnail_size parameter to work with a given pixel size. The parameter can be a word, but also a size in X- and Y-dimension, as I understand it. Can someone give me an example of how to write this? Thanks.

Comment: Nika, can you tell me what kind of styling you added and where in order to get the text to wrap around the image nicely? It's not working on my website.

Comment: If you are using the 'list category posts' plugin, there is an option to the catlist command called 'template'. This plugin has a default template file, found in the plugin's folder, and called default.php. You can create a new folder called list-category-posts under under 'wp-content/themes/your-theme-folder' and put the default.php file there. To add styling you can either edit this file or create a new file. It must be in the same folder. Call it f ex news.php and use template=news in your catlist command. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/

Comment: Try adding .lcp_catlist img { float: left; } in your style.css.

Answer (score 1):

What plug-in are you using to display the post thumbnails? This one works : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-thumbnail/. It requires you to use the [regenerate thumbnails plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) on existing images, but after you install it the thumbnails will be the size you specify. You might be able to install the regenerate thumbnails plugin to get the current plugin to work. If not try the one I linked to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't aware that I needed a plugin to display thumbnails. Thought it was builtin. I installed the regenerate thumbnails plugin, and it works, although I had to add styling to the "list category post" content in order to get the text to flow around the thumbnails.

Comment: Regarding the first plugin you mentioned, WP Category Thumbnail, is it safe to test it while I also have activated 'list category posts' plugin? Our sites relies on the latter, but I could schedule a time at some late night hour to take the site down and test it.

Comment: They might conflict with each-other, so it's probably best to wait for a time when it's ok to deactivate the current one. If you provide a link to the one you're using I'll test it out. I did a search for the one you're using but several similar ones popped up and I didn't know which you were using.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/

Comment: It's called 'list category posts'. Sorry, forgot an 's'. Here's the link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/

Comment: I also have another issue. I need to put captions underneath the images listed by the "list category posts" plugin or any other plugin which does the same. Is there a way to do that? Any recommendations?